# FileSystemWatcher event trigger problem(s)

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

It seems like , FileSystemWatcher triggers events more than once. Here is my settings ;

```
 watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
 watcher.Path = @"D:\testSpace";
 watcher.InternalBufferSize = 1024*64;
 watcher.Deleted += Triggered;
 watcher.Changed += Triggered;
 watcher.Created += Triggered;
 watcher.Error += ErrorOccured;
 watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
 watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

 watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

- If you change a document , Document changed event triggered twice.
- New folder created event does not get triggered unless a new file created under the folder.
- Deleted event not fired ( tried using shift delete as well)

do you guys know any work around for these issues ?

Comment: You don't say which events fire twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx):

> Common file system operations might
> raise more than one event. For
> example, when a file is moved from one
> directory to another, several
> OnChanged  and some OnCreated  and
> OnDeleted  events might be raised.
> Moving a file is a complex operation
> that consists of multiple simple
> operations, therefore raising multiple
> events. Likewise, some applications
> (for example, antivirus software)
> might cause additional file system
> events that are detected by
> FileSystemWatcher.

The solution to your 1st issue is described in the link.

Comment: Dear Sir, Maybe you could take a look at my question in regard to your answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184472/fileinfo-exceptions. Thanks in advance